# I don't understand how the vector equation for the line is created and why the w with vector sign identified by minus angle

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't understand how the vector equation for the line is created and why the w (with the vector sign) is identified by minus angle and opposite to the other w;(-sinө,cosө); and where did they take  s ?

Comment: You can find a short explanation [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/normals-planes.html) as well as in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524246/why-are-the-coefficients-of-the-equation-of-a-plane-the-normal-vector-of-a-plane?rq=1) on the right. The latter talks about a plane, but the principle is the same for a line in $\mathbb R^2$ (or for any hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question in a slightly different order to how you asked it. First why $\omega$ is $\hat{\omega}$ "switched with the minus sign..."
This is because we want those vectors to be perpendicular, meaning that if we take the dot product we get zero.
In this regard it is obvious that $\hat\omega = <-sin(\theta), cos(\theta)> $ is perpendicular to $\omega = <cos(\theta), sin(\theta)> $ as then $\omega \cdot \hat\omega = <-sin(\theta), cos(\theta)>\cdot<cos(\theta), sin(\theta)> = -sin(\theta)cos(\theta) + cos(\theta)sin(\theta)=0$
Which means that these vectors are perpendicular. So when $\omega$ is perpendicular to the line as shown,  $\hat\omega$ is parallel to the line.
Now, we parametrize the set of straight lines, using their distance from the origin and at which angle they are oriented. The distance from the origin is the $t$ shown in the diagram and is the distance traveled along the vector perpendicular to the line, from the origin as shown. This is where the $t\omega$ comes from.

The angle, $\theta$ shows in which direction the line is oriented, but you seem to understand this, so I will move on to your next question:
The $s$ then shows how far along the line you travel from where the right angle in the diagram is drawn, this gives the $s\hat\omega$ in the formula. A specific $s$ gives a specific point on the line, but the s is not used to parametrise the line itself, that whole line is determined by the $t$ and the $\theta$. I hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer, but please use MathJax to format your mathematical expressions.