# Find the $2$ vectors with length of $1$ normal to the plane with the equation $5x - 6y + 4z = 10$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

To my understanding, a vector with a length of $1$ is a unit vector. If it is normal to the plane it is perpendicular, so if the equation was $5x-6y+4z = 0$ and in vector form $\langle 5, -6, 4\rangle$.

Then our unit vector that is normal to the plane would simply be $\langle \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{-6}, \frac{1}{4}\rangle$.

However I am thrown off since the equation is not set to equal $0$ but instead $10$ and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Careful: the equation of the plane is *not* a vector. Rather the normal vector and the plane are perpendicular, thus must have dot product 0: see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524246/why-are-the-coefficients-of-the-equation-of-a-plane-the-normal-vector-of-a-plane) which explains why.

Comment: "*our unit vector ... would simply be*" $\,$ Except that's neither normal, nor a unit vector. $\,$ "*the equation is not set to equal 0 but instead 10*" $\,$ The $\,=0\,$ equation is the plane through the origin. The $\,=10\,$ equation, and more generally $\,=C\,$ equations, are planes parallel to that one. They all have the same normal vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the normal to the plane is $\vec{n} = \langle 5,-6,4\rangle$. So you are looking for a vector $\vec{p} \parallel \vec{n}$ such that $||\vec{p}|| = 1$. Say $\vec{p} = \langle x,y,z\rangle \implies x = 5r, y = -6r, z = 4r \implies (5r)^2+(-6r)^2+(4r)^2 = 1\implies 77r^2=1\implies r = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{77}}$. So the $2$ vectors you are looking for are: $\vec{p} = \pm \langle \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{77}}, -\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{77}}, \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{77}} \rangle$.